# Internet Explorer 7 & 8 Margin Display Issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

I was having a small problem with center aligning a DIV in IE7 and 8. There are some minor height issues also, but ill cross that bridge when I get to it...

I have always used

```
middleAlign {
    width:someAbsWidth;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

to center my DIVS in all browsers, and it has worked fine. But now, I am having problems with this method in IE7 and 8. They do not center the div; rather it acts as if the margin-left is 0. Could it be other CSS rules affecting the margin display in IE?

I have uploaded the page to my server; the page is viewable here: http://drafts.thatcompdude.com/NewSite/

The page renders just fine in FF 3.6; Chrome 8.0.

Thank you;

--Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is in quirks mode because of the comment at the top. Remove it and it'll be standards mode and it'll start working.

Comment: I had no idea that that would happen! Thanks for your help, crisis averted.

Comment: Err sorry but you wouldent happen to know why the height of the dialog boxes are the minimum width in IE also>